# Passport.JS to get Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, passport.js, google-calendar-api

I am currently trying to build a Calendar app in Node.JS hooked with Google Calendar. However, I have been struggling with trying to get a Calendar from the Google API. I have downloaded the GoogleApis npm package to assist PassportJS, but I can not seem to get passport to interact with GoogleAPIs. I was trying to find a method of using the already authenticated user to get a Calendar, but google has yielded no results. Is there a way to use Passport.JS to get a Google Calendar, or do I need to abandon PassportJS for this task entirely?

Here is the express route I am currently using to attempt to get a Calendar.

```
let auth = passport.authenticate('google', { 
scope: ['profile', 'email', 
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events', 
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']
})
/*
I want to know if there is a way to Get The Calendar without the Code below or if I can use Passportjs for the Credentials Section
*/
 const client = google.auth.getClient({
        credentials: credentials 
        scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'],
      })
    calendar.events.list({
        calendarId: 'CALID',
...
```

Answer (score 0):

PassportJS won't make the API calls to the calendar API, it's sole purpose is to authenticate the user, you seem to be missing the whole OAuth flow before you make any call to the calendar API.

At first you need to setup you Project on google cloud console and enable the Calendar API https://console.cloud.google.com/ to generate the JSON for the credentials.

With the credentials in hand you can simply load them as such:

```
const keys = require('./your_oauth_keys.json');
```

You then need to specify the auth strategy

```
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: keys.web.client_id,
    clientSecret:  keys.web.client_secret,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/callback",
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      userProfile=profile;
      return done(null, userProfile);
  }
));
```

Then assuming you are using express just add the required routes

```
app.get('/auth', 
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope : scopes }));
 
app.get('/auth/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/error' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect success.
    res.redirect('/success');
  });
```

You should also add http://localhost:3000/ to the oauth policy allowed urls